# Why does NSNotificationCenter post cause a" unrecognized selector sent to instance?"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, Storyboards, iOS 6.2) with several classes.  In one class, when I finish posting, I post a notification which I expect another class to catch.  Not happening!

Here is the code to register the notifications, which I have in AppDelegate.m:

```
    // add observers for notificaations
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(calendarTapNotification:)
                                             name:@"calendarDateSelected" object:nil ];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(notificationOfAppointmentMade:)
                                             name:@"appointmentMade" object:nil ];
```

Here is the code where I post a notification for one of the observers:

if(aDate != nil)  {  //  if user tapped outside of valid date range, aDate will be nil

```
    [passedData setObject:aDate forKey:@"selectedDate"];

    //  post notification CFGregorianDate has been tapped and pass selected date
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"calendarDateSelected" object:self userInfo:passedData];

}
```

And this is the code where I handle the "calendarTapNotification" notification which never gets called:

```
- (void) calendarTapNotification:(NSNotification *) notification  {

//  was the calendar tapped?
if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"calendarDateSelected"])  {

    //  get the data in the dictiionary
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    //        NSLog(@"\ndict contents: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"selectedDate"]);  //  this is NSDate class!

    // gets the year, month, and day for selected date
    NSDate *selectedDate = [dict objectForKey:@"selectedDate"];
    //        NSLog(@"\n\ndict-selectedDate: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"selectedDate"]);


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // get default calendar
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: selectedDate];
    //        NSLog(@"\n\ndateFromComponents: %@", components);

    // create start and end of date
    NSDate *startDate = [self beginningOfDay: [calendar dateFromComponents:components]];
    NSDate *endDate = [self endOfDay: [calendar dateFromComponents:components]];
    //        NSLog(@"\nstartDate: %@    endDate: %@", startDate, endDate);

    //  create the predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate =  ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((aStartTime > %@) AND (aStartTime <= %@))", startDate, endDate]);

    //  find all appointments with that selected date (AppointmentInfo is NSManagedContext; appointmentInfo is NSArray)
    appointmentInfo = [AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];

    SingletonAppointments *sharedInstance = [SingletonAppointments sharedInstance];  //  initialize
    //        if(sharedInstance.globalApptList.count > 0)  //  <--------------  TODO
    //            [sharedInstance.globalApptList removeAllObjects];                   //removeAllObjects];  //  clear out the old stuff

    if(appointmentInfo.count > 0)  {
        for (AppointmentInfo *appt in appointmentInfo) {
            sharedInstance.globalApptList = appointmentInfo;  //  move data to sharedInstance
        }
    }
    else  {
        sharedInstance.globalApptList = nil;
    }
    // NSLog(@"\n\nsharedInstance.count: %d", sharedInstance.globalApptList.count);

    //  re-draw the schedule
    [self.subViewData setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

}

This is the output from the "crash":

> 2013-04-17 12:58:47.942 saori[11294:c07] -[AppDelegate calendarTapNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a25c60
>   2013-04-17 12:58:47.943 saori[11294:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate calendarTapNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a25c60'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2701012 0x19efe7e 0x278c4bd 0x26f0bbc 0x26f094e 0x14b04f9 0x275b0c5 0x26b5efa 0x13e4bb2 0x7de8 0x80eb 0x966cef 0x966f02 0x944d4a 0x936698 0x2b7edf9 0x2b7ead0 0x2676bf5 0x2676962 0x26a7bb6 0x26a6f44 0x26a6e1b 0x2b7d7e3 0x2b7d668 0x933ffc 0x297d 0x28a5 0x1)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I have tried everything I know of, read the two Apple docs on NSNotifications and looked at Google and SO and found nothing)

Why doesn't it handler for notification get called? (which I suppose will lead to what is causing the crash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've implemented

```
calendarTapNotification:
notificationOfAppointmentMade:
```

in your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: In the AppDelegate?  Why can't they stay in the classes where they logically belong?  I only added the -addObserver to the AppDelegate so all of the other classes would have access... no?

Comment: You're adding `self` as the observer from AppDelegate.m, so the responsible to respond those notifications is the AppDelegate. If you want another object to receive the notifications, you should do `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:instanceOfTheObjectYouWant...`

Comment: ... Or register those notifications from the .m class that implement the methods, instead of AppDelegate.m

Comment: I wanted them there because I wanted to get the first "view" that was presented (it can be one of two)... arggghhhhhh!

Comment: You mean two different views may handle those notifications? Well, you could have AppDelegate to 'redirect' the call to the current view if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you both... I removed the code from the AppDelegate and placed it in the class that is handling the notifications.  Works like a champ now... thanks again... :D

Answer (score 2):

If you have not implemented the `calendarTapNotification:` method then implement it, secondly make sure you are using the parameter for your method as you are using `:`.

When you are adding an observer for a notification then you should be able to listen to it, for listening to the notification, it should be posted. Make sure you are posting the `calendarDateSelected` notification in your code. I don't see anywhere you have posted.

Comment: Code added... I thought I had everything... things started to go south when I added the second notification (appointmentMade). :-{

Comment: you are not posting the `calendarDateSelected` notification

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, yes I am... thought I had the code in the question... posted the wrong code... it's there now, and it is the line that is causing the crash.